# Rcpp exportPattern

Tags: r, package, rcpp

I wrote a package that uses `Rcpp` and `RcppArmadillo`. `Rcpp.package.skeleton` sets up a basic package structure for packages including `Rcpp`. Among these insertions is the line `exportPattern("ˆ[[:alpha:]]+")` in `NAMESPACE`. It defines that any functions starting with an alphabetic character are to be exported.

Assume that the package contains the following functions:

- `r1`: the R function available to the package user
- `r2`: another R function, not called by the user, but called by `r1`
- `c1`: a C++ function, not called by the user, but called by `r1`
- `c2`: a C++ function, not called by the user, but called by `r2`

The repository maintainers insist that I must not use `exportPattern("ˆ[[:alpha:]]+")`, meaning that I have to export functions explicitly. If I understand correctly, in a regular R package (without C++ content), I would only have to export the functions available to the user, i.e. `export("r1")` in this case. What is the adequate setting in a package that does rely on C++? The C++ functions need to be exported from the file in the `src` directory to R. But does that also mean that they need to be exports in `NAMESPACE`: `export("r1")`, `export("c1")`, `export("c2")`?

Comment: Can you expand on "The repository maintainers insist that I must not use `exportPattern("ˆ[[:alpha:]]+")`" ? I use that in my own packages ...

Comment: See comment below your answer.

Comment: Maybe you typed the pattern by hand and injected a non-standard character. Now CRAN tells you not to use a non-standard character.  Is it that easy?

Comment: I voted to close (and delete) this question. The root of the problem was an encoding issue and apparently not what the questions elaborates on. Therefore, it is unlikely to benefit other users.

Comment: I agree, and I (unsuccessfully, sadly, my bad) hinted that way as the `<cb><86>` below was a strong clue.  I still quite understand how/why `roxygen2` would have created something invalid, and without a reproducible example we will never know.  BTW you as the OP can just delete the question -- no voting needed on your part.   As for the 'how do I control which function is public and exported' that is standard `NAMESPACE` fare and I hope you will find help in existing documentation.  Rcpp(Armadillo) just plugs into the framework.

Comment: Thanks for your help. SO does not allow me to delete the question because it has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the expanded export tag in your C++ code and have the generated R function start with a dot meaning it will not be export.  For example, in the [RcppAnnoy](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppAnnoy) package I do this for a helper function

```
#include "RcppAnnoy.h"

// [[Rcpp::export(.annoy_version)]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector annoy_version() {
  return Rcpp::IntegerVector::create(Rcpp::Named("major")=RCPPANNOY_VERSION_MAJOR,
                                     Rcpp::Named("minor")=RCPPANNOY_VERSION_MINOR,
                                     Rcpp::Named("patch")=RCPPANNOY_VERSION_PATCH);
}
```

This function then has to be called with `:::` as it is not exported:

```
> RcppAnnoy:::.annoy_version()
major minor patch 
    0     0    18 
>
```

and `NAMESPACE` has the standard minimal of the regular expression along with the required (and of course documented) `useDynLib()` and `import()`:

```
useDynLib(RcppAnnoy, .registration=TRUE)
import(methods, Rcpp)
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")    # export all identifiers starting with letters
```

There are numerous other packages like it on CRAN, so I am a little, well, "surprised" by your assertion about the `NAMESPACE` file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. CRAN notified me that they will remove my package unless I change this line. In particular, they complain about the `^` being identified as a non-ASCII character: `R> tools:::showNonASCIIfile("NAMESPACE")` `exportPattern("<cb><86>[[:alpha:]]+")`.

Comment: Well would that not appear to be a *different* pattern and not the one created by R itself (try `package.skeleton()` and/or `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`.) ?  Bit hard to blame Rcpp for woes you imposed yourself.

Comment: For what it is worth this link shows you the paragraph in base R's `utils` package where `NAMESPACE` is created _with the very pattern I showed you_:  https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/c57b018dc333af4b459ccf10bf81d44fd7ca3e5d/src/library/utils/R/package.skeleton.R#L121-L146

Comment: I would recommend you try a new sample package created by `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton("testpackage")` and compare the two `NAMESPACE` files.  This works reliably for everybody else, there is no reason for it not to work for you, but based on the information provided by you I cannot help you any further.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to reply earlier, but got distracted by other tasks today. Sorry. I actually generate `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` via roxygen. I think I first generated the basic structure via `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` or `RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton()` and transformed it into roxygen syntax. I manually retyped part of the problematic line today, and now it should be ok. There might have been an encoding issue with one of the characters (which was not obvious in UTF-8) that occurred while copying or storing the code.

Comment: According to your suggestions, it appears to be ok to use a regular expression here - despite CRAN complaints. Thus, I will submit the package with `exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")` again. By the way, I am not blaming `Rcpp` for anything here.

Comment: I have been trying to help you with several answers and to be perfectly frank: I still have no idea what your perceived problem is.  We talk a lot around here how _minimally complete verifiable examples_ help -- see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Maybe have a look at that before the next question?